# Проблема с преобразованием строки к типу Double

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть форма. На форме есть TextBox, ввожу в него значение 0.27 и получаю ошибку: неверный входной формат строки. Как устранить эту ошибку? С запятой работает, с точкой не хочет.

```
double X = double.Parse(previousText.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ваша операционная система русифицирована, и поэтому  Decimical Separator (разделитель дробной части от целой в десятичной дроби) установлен запятой. В английских версиях за сепаратор принята точка.

Comment: Да а как быть если мне требуется поддержка и английской и русской?

Comment: Можно просто изменить дробный разделитель в системе, используя WinAPI-функцию :

      SetDecimalSeparator('.')

Comment: тогда можно использовать такой подход:

     NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
     provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
     double X = Convert.ToDouble(previousText.ToString(), provider);

[Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9s9ak971.aspx)

Comment: @Spectre, ну да)